# vim auto complete custom list

Tags: vim, scripting

I had these two questions about this function

```
" how do I load a file into a list here?
" set some variable  

func! CustomComplete() 


" and then read the variable here so that b:list = a \n split file ?
let b:list = ["spoogle","spangle","frizzle"]
let b:matches = []
```

The intent is that I can just hit a hot key and auto complete a list from the file system.

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=CustomComplete()<CR>

" how do I load a file into a list?
func! CustomComplete()

echom 'select word under cursor'
let b:word = expand('<cword>')
echom '->'.b:word.'<-'
echom 'save position'
let b:position = col('.')
echom '->'.b:position.'<-'
normal e
normal l
echom 'move to end of word'

" and then read the list here?
let b:list = ["spoogle","spangle","frizzle"]
let b:matches = []


echom 'begin checking for completion'
for item in b:list
echom 'checking '
echom '->'.item.'<-'
  if(match(item,'^'.b:word)==0)
  echom 'adding to matches'
  echom '->'.item.'<-'
  call add(b:matches,item)
  endif
endfor
call complete(b:position, b:matches)
return ''
    endfunc
```

Comment: Can you maybe make your question a bit more clear?  Pulling it out of the code might help get more people looking at it.

Comment: thats fairly clear. I need to read a file into an array in a language thats 30 years old and I am a little out of practice with.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the filenames via `glob()`, like this, which offers all text files in your home directory for completion:

```
inoremap <F5> <C-R>=ListFiles()<CR>

func! ListFiles()
    let files = map(split(glob('~/*.txt'), "\n"), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t")')
    call complete(col('.'), files)
    return ''
endfunc
```

To strip off the path, I used `fnamemodify()`, which I `map()`'ed over the list.

Comment: Any idea how I could use this while not in insert mode, when presenting the user with an input('Give me a file!') prompt?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn `let c = confirm("Choose file:", join(files, "\n")) | put =files[c-1]` brings up a user dialog and then inserts the choice as a new line.

Comment: complete is nicer; you can choose things not in the list, and it filters the list by prefix. I found a way to do all that in input, by giving a customlist function:
`let r = input('Choose: ', '', 'customlist,GetFiles')`. Define GetFiles to return a list of strings.